# Flutter : Not able to generate release apk in after migrating to AndroidX, getting error for camera plugin

Tags: android, flutter, apk, release, androidx

After migrate my app into AndroidX, I am able to generate and run debug apk in my flutter project, but when i try to build release apk, i am getting following error.

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                                                                           
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                     293.0s (!)
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin camera...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...                             
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'... Done                    0.8s


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'camera'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s


The plugin camera could not be built due to the issue above.
```

Flutter version : v1.12.13+hotfix.5.

Flutter channel : stable.

Compile SDK Version : 28.

Min SDK Version : 21.

Target SDK Version : 28.

Comment: seems like your SDK location is wrong! Try deleting `android/local.properties` and then run `flutter clean && flutter packages get`